# Writing query for form in Joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-template

I am a beginner with Joomla. I am using template sitegroundJ16-2. I designed a form for around 9 text fields. I also made a table in the database. Now I want to write a query to connect to database to insert data in the dbase and retrieve data.

I am not able to figure out where to write query.

In the article where I designed that form?  Where can I locate my articles in directory structure?

Answer (score 1):

The code to connect to the database is:

```
$db = & JFactory::getDBO();
```

The code to insert a query would be something like this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `#__yourtable` (`firstname`, `lastname`) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname');";
$db->setQuery($query);
```

The code to retrieve information from a database could be something like this:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM #__yourtable ORDER BY id DESC';
$db->setQuery($query);
```

You won't be able to add this to a Joomla article, you will either need to create a component or find a free one and adapt it as GDP said, or create a module and embed it in an article.

Answer (score 0):

In spite of the very broad nature of your question, you'll need to write a component for joomla.  A  starting point [Hello World](http://help.joomla.org/content/view/773/125/) would be the logical starting point, but I'd suggest finding and downloading a similar extension and modifying that.  If it's just a form that you're looking to create, I'd strongly recommend one of the free extensions that do that for you that can be found at the [JED](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/contacts-and-feedback/forms).